# Stop while loop from going over and over? Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have an issue where my code keeps repeating a statement over and over when I don't want it to.

Here is my code:

```
def gameMake():

    while emptySp(): #already written (checks if the space is available for the user to put in their token)


        print("Player 1")
        mycol = input("Please choose a column (1-" + str(columns))

        if coluser == columns:
            mycol = input("Please choose a column to place your piece in (1-" + str(columns))

        elif:
            rowuse = rows


            while x >= 1:
                if board[x][coluser] == board[r][c]
                    board[x][coluser] == PONE #PONE = "o" (the token)


                else:

                    i = 0
                    i = i + 1
```

Example of the output and what I'm getting: (the board inputted is 5x5)

```
Player 1 
Please choose a column (1-5): 1
Player 1 
Please choose a column (1-5): 2
Player 1 
Please choose a column (1-5):3
Player 1 
Please choose a column (1-5): 4
Player 1 
Please choose a column (1-5): 5


IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is supposed to accept numbers 1-5 as a valid column number and then print out the current board using the board function I already created! If its any number other than 1-5 it is supposed to re-prompt the user! What is going wrong with my code? Why is there an Index error?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of `i` in your code? You set it to zero and then add 1 to it.

Comment: Put an `if-statement` at the end that checks whether your column is more than 5. If yes, break.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first two statements inside else? You first set `i = 0`, then increment it, but the next time you enter `else` again, `i` would be reset to 0 first.

Comment: One problem might be that lists in python have a zero-based index, not a one-based index. `board_row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` has valid indices `board_row[0]` through `board_row[4]`. `board_row[5]` is out of range. So, while you ask for `column` and accept `1`, you're probably going to need to translate that to `0` at some place in your code.

Comment: It would be nice if you will provide the **real** code as the code you provided **doesn't behave as you write**, e. g. the prompt for user input is `Please choose a column (1-5` (without `)` and `:` at the end) - so how we may trust you that some important parts are not changed, too?

Comment: I figured it out! thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not checking that the number is in the range of 1-X, you are just checking that the number is >= 1.

You would want to update the while statement to read `while x >= 1 and x <= columns:`

You may also want to use the a try/except block for your prompted input, `mycol = input("Please..`. I bring this up because currently your script will fail if someone enters A-Z or any other special character.

Answer (score 0):

From the example input/output that you show, it seems like you always end up in the inner most `if` clause.
Here, `board[x][coluser] == PONE` is performing a comparison, not an assignment, so it evaluates to true or false, but doesn't change anything in the rest of your program. So `emptySp()` always returns true, because nothing has changed.
Secondly, what is "#Check for any win with win function"? What is the win function? Again, inside that `if` clause, no part of the code is being changed, so whatever caused `emptySp()` to evaluate to true the first time, continues to stay the same.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying! How would I assign PONE to that element?Also i put the #Check for win function comment there because I was going to add my function that checks if a player won or not after making sure my current code was working!

Comment: The assignment operator is `=`, the comparison one is `==`.